# Twitter Like User Page

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, profile-page

Hello,

Every consider creating a twitter-like view, giving each user twitter-like screen with their recent activity to questions answered, asked, or commented, plus their recent badge list, even allowing users to link up together?

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 3):

All of that exists except for the "allowing users to link up" part; one of the tabs on your profile is labeled [activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231716?tab=activity)

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the activity page(envelope icon on the top bar) or your own user profile page, you can already see all this.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of us use Twitter already.  If a user wants to make their contact information available, they'll put it in their profile.

Comment: I think the OP isn't talking about Twitter itself, but something Twitter-esque.

Comment: @waiwai933: Twitter is Twitter-esque.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, we have Q&A, chat, user profile pages that give plenty of info limited by how much we need to see.